# How to write code that changes the value of a variable automatically every week?

Tags: java, android, date

I am writing an app that tracks an exercise routine and multiplies the time or reps for the exercises by 10% every week. As I'm a total beginner to Android Studio and Java, I'm having trouble understanding how to write code that executes every time I launch the app and how to write code that only executes once on the first launch.

Here's my code, I have an Exercises class, and in the MainActivity I wrote

```
Exercises stretch = new Exercises("Stretch", 360);

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); //execute this every day
int compare_day = day;
if(day-compare_day>=7){
warmup.setTime((int) (warmup.getTime()*1.1));
int compare_day = day;
}
```

How do I write the code that would update the **day** variable every day, but not the **compare_day** variable? And is there a better solution, one that would do it automatically, without having to open the app every day?

Comment: You can use **[SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)** to keep values.

Comment: @PratikButani could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Everything is explained in that link. You must have to read once.

Comment: @PratikButani so if I store the compare_day variable in the SharedPreference and keep the day variable in MainActivity, the day variable will update every time I open the app, but not the compare_day variable?

Comment: Yes, compare_day will update when you commit the changes in preference.

Comment: Did you do a tutorial or read some documentation about Java or Android? Did you take a course? If you did, you'd know how to do what you want to do.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. `LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )`